# Angular 6 compare two JSON Arrays

Tags: arrays, json, angular

I am fetching notifications using API. Now here is the scenario:

1- I called the API, got 2 records and stored them in local variable (`notifications`) to show in view.

```
[{"id": 1, "notification": "bla"}, {"id": 2, "notification": "bla bla"}]
```

2- I am calling the same API to check for new notification after every 5 seconds. This time I need to compare the API response with the local variable, so if no new notification (different `id`) is in the record, don't push in local variable, other push.

I have tried something like this:

```
var val = JSON.parse(data);
if( val.length > 0 ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < val.length; i++ ) {
        this.notifications.forEach(element => {
            if( element.id != val[i].id ) {
                this.notifications.push(val[i]);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

But its adding duplicate records. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Array.find()` to find the duplicate object in the `val` array.

```js
var notifications = [{"id": 1, "notification": "bla"}, {"id": 2, "notification": "bla bla"}];

var data = `[{"id": 1, "notification": "bla"}, {"id": 4, "notification": "bla bla bla"}]`

var val = JSON.parse(data);
if( val.length > 0 ) {
   val.forEach((obj)=>{
     var existNotification = notifications.find(({id}) => obj.id === id);
     if(!existNotification){
       notifications.push(obj);
     }
   });
}
console.log(notifications);
```

Currently, you are getting duplicated element because the `id` value is compared against all the existing `id` values in `notifications` array. So, if one of the `id` do not match with another, it is pushed immediately into the `notifications` array. So, the better way and simple way is to use a `find` operation on the array to check the existing object.

Comment: that's exactly I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @MuzammilVersiani glad to help :)

Comment: What If I have to compare whole data like id & notification and so on. In above , you are comparing only first object of array, right?

Answer (score 1):

A more robust way to handle this could be by using `map` in JS.

Rather than iterating the `notifications` (size = m) for every object in the `data` (size = n) would result in more time complexity of `O(m x n)`.

Hence it could be done in `O(n)` as below:-

```js
var notifications = new Map();

// assuming you get this at the beginning
var data1 = `[{"id": 1, "notification": "bla"}, {"id": 2, "notification": "bla bla"}]`;

checkAndAddNotification(data1);

// assuming you get this at the second time
var data2 = `[{"id": 1, "notification": "bla"}, {"id": 4, "notification": "bla bla bla"}]`

checkAndAddNotification(data2);

function checkAndAddNotification(data){
  var val = JSON.parse(data);
  
  if (val){
    val.forEach((obj)=>{
     var existNotification = notifications.get(obj.id);
     
     if(!existNotification){
       notifications.set(obj.id, obj);
     }
   });
  }
}

console.log(notifications);

notifications.forEach((notification) => console.log(notification));
```

**Please open the browser console as well while running the code.**

Even if you plan to iterate over the map, the order would be preserved in the order the objects were inserted. [Please look here for more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Objects_and_maps_compared).

Comment: How is this robust? This is adding an extra `forEach()`

Comment: Thats why the complexity is `O(n)`, my friend. I am preventing the complexity incurred by using `find()` method. And if you are talking about `notifications.forEach`, then this is just to prove that the notifications are in the order they were inserted.

Comment: @AnkitSharma I think you don't even need to check `if(!existNotification)` if it already exists, it will override the value?